# Failed to set client format on recorded audio file ('hwiu')

Tags: ios, objective-c, ezaudio

I am recording an audio file but still the initializing the recorder giving me this error. Can you please look into this?

```
self.microphone = [EZMicrophone microphoneWithDelegate:self];
[self.microphone startFetchingAudio];
self.recorder1 = [EZRecorder recorderWithURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:outputFileURL1.path]
                                   clientFormat:[self.microphone audioStreamBasicDescription]
                                       fileType:EZRecorderFileTypeM4A delegate:self];
```

I have deleted the previous file also but still I am getting this error.

Comment: Whats the error?

Comment: What is EZMicrophone?

Comment: @SaurabhJain Check this.

https://github.com/syedhali/EZAudio#EZRecorder

Comment: @SNarula Please check the question heading.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the problem at my end, the problem was that EZRecorder was initializing two times.